# Using jquery to filter out duplicate data in a json populated select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a select box that I am populating with data from a json file using the code below:

```
function getType(str) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx',
        type: 'GET',
        format: 'json',
        data: {
            take: 100,
            skip: 0
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var option = $('<option>').text(item.type.name)
            option.appendTo("#choose");
        })
    })
};
getType();
```

The problem is that the returned value type.name has loads of duplicates in it, I would like to filter out these duplicates to only show each unique value one time. Im a bit stuck on where to start with this though so help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you also post a sample of your `data`?

Comment: {
        "id": 1,
        "typeId": 2,
        "type": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "sample string 2"
        },
        "start": "2015-08-13T07:46:33.9502774+10:00",
        "end": "2015-08-13T07:46:33.9502774+10:00",
        "hasBooking": true,
        "hasDropIns": true,
        "consultant": {
          "firstName": "sample string 1",
         "lastName": "sample string 2"
        },

Comment: @GaryBurton check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and creating an array to track unique names, you can build up a filtered data array to then iterate over to display your unique datasets.

```
function getType(str) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'GET',
    format: 'json',
    data: { take: 100, skip: 0 },
  })
  .done(function(data) {
      var filteredData = [];
      var uniqueNames  = [];
      data.filter(function (data) {
        if (uniqueNames.indexOf(data.type.name) < 0) {
          uniqueNames.push(data.type.name);
          filteredData.push(data);
        }
      });

      $.each(filteredData, function(i, item) {
        var option = $('<option>').text(item.type.name)
        option.appendTo("#choose");
      })
   })
};
getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a condition to append options only if options with same text does not exist in the `#choose` select, using selector `[text="someText"]`.

```
function getType(str) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx',
        type: 'GET',
        format: 'json',
        data: {
            take: 100,
            skip: 0
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if($("#choose").children('option[text="' + item.type.name + '"]').length == 0){
                var option = $('<option>').text(item.type.name)
                option.appendTo("#choose");
            }
        })
    })
};
getType();
```

Comment: @lshettyl `$("#choose").children('option[text="' + item.type.name + '"]').length == 0` my code only adds a new option only if there is **no** `option` with the proposed text exists in the `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippets.

```
.done(function(data) {
var records=[];
$.each(data, function (i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, records) === -1) records.push(el); //filters the duplicate elements
     });
$.each(records, function(i, item) {
    var option = $('<option>').text(item.type.name)
    option.appendTo("#choose");
    });
});
```

**Update:** 
Try this code snippet if you want to filter out the `name` from the json `data` variable.

```
.done(function(data) {
var records=[], nameList = [];
$.each(data, function (i, elem) {
    nameList.push(elem.type.name);
     });
$.each(nameList, function (i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, records) === -1) records.push(el);
     });
$.each(records, function(i, item) {
    var option = $('<option>').text(item)
    option.appendTo("#choose");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cant seem to get this to work, am I missing something?

Comment: You need filter out the `name` from the json `data` variable?

Comment: Yes thats right, the select box is populated with the information from type.name, which includes lots of repeated information

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter like this :

```
var unique=data.filter(function(item,i,a){
    return i==data.indexOf(item.type.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to filter out the value that's already been found. Please find comments inline for more info.

```js
//Sample data
var data = [
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 2" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 2" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 1" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 2" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 2" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 4" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 2" }, 
    },
    {
        "type": { "id": 1, "name": "sample string 3" }, 
    }
]

//Create an empty object
var $items = $();
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    //Construct the option
    var $option = $('<option/>', {text: item.type["name"]});
    //Add it to the bucket only if it's not already added!
    if (!$items.filter(":contains(" + item.type["name"] + ")").length) {
        $items = $items.add($option);
    }
});
//Always append outside the loop!
$("#choose").append($items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choose"></select>
```